# Mex endpoint not Found in WCf

Tags: wcf

I am using a example to do my first wcf service..
I am using is
[this example](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2010/06/16/wcf-simple-example-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

giving me error 
mex endpoint not found.

i have included appconfig file in console host and included following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

can anyone please help me ht iam not able to run console host...

Comment: If you are not able to run console host then the problem is elsewhere. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: iam using visual studio 2008 and framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually configure a mex endpoint for your service?

That would look something like this:

```
<service name="MyService" ...>
    <!-- actual service endpoints here -->
    <endpoint address="/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

Comment: i added <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  
    <client>
      <endpoint address ="http://localhost:8080/MyService/EmailValidator"
                binding ="wsHttpBinding"
                contract ="EmailService.EmailValidator">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration> in app.config on console host

Comment: but still its showing exception..emailservice has zero application end points

Comment: Not sure why you're showing me client configuration here. Mex support is something that has to be configured on the service side.

Comment: Iam new to WCf.. and iam following article.. wht is given above. .Service side means EmailService is my service for validation meail.. console host is console application.. which i use to host to service.. app.config file includes in consolehost

Answer (score 0):

> I am using visual studio 2008 and
>   framework 3.5

And that is the whole problem. The example you are referring is for WCF 4 which uses something called default endpoints or simplified configuration. Nothing like this exists in WCF 3.5. You must manually configure your service and all its endpoints!

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="EmailService.EmailValidator" behaviorConfiguration="Metadata"> 
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="EmailService.IEmailValidator" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Metadata">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: ok.. so i added endpoint in app.config in console host...it is giving me error 
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: This collection already contains
an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection.
Parameter name: item
   at System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, Uri i
tem)
   at System.Collections.Generic.SynchronizedCollection`1.Add(T item)
   at